# With Camel and Guice, how can I inject an SQS client?

Tags: java, apache-camel, guice, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS client thats set up elsewhere in my Guice modules that I'd like to use in Camel.  Currently, it seems that the only way to make use of it is to somehow add it to the `CameContext`'s registry.  This seems ugly -- I don't need another container to deal with.  I also didn't have to do anything like this when I previously used Camel and Spring.

How can I have Guice provide the SQS client without having to use JNDI?

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sure.  I tried adding credentials directly to the route, but that didn't seem to work.  Even if it did, I don't like the fact that the keys get printed to the log.  The work-around I came up with was to put a bit in one of my Guice modules to create the CamelContext with a SimpleRegistry and add the AmazonSQSClient to that registry.  The goal is to avoid that ugly work-around and JNDI.